# Replace expression into javascript variable placeholders

Tags: javascript

Need javascript regex pattern to convert all **{{variableName}}** expression into Javascript variable placeholders like **${variableName}** in a provided string.

```
let str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor {{variable1}}, sit amet consectetur {{otherVaraible}} elit. Iure facilis quaerat obcaecati tempore {{variable2}} praesentium, nisi culpa vero';
```

**Expected:**

```
let str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor ${variable1}, sit amet consectetur ${otherVaraible} elit. Iure facilis quaerat obcaecati tempore ${variable2} praesentium, nisi culpa vero';
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way's use replace with regex. Follow as code:

```js
 run1.onclick = function() {
  output1.innerHTML = input1.value.replace( /{{(.*?)}}/g, '${$1}'); 
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text" value="'Lorem ipsum dolor {{variable1}}, sit amet consectetur {{otherVaraible}} elit. Iure facilis quaerat obcaecati tempore {{variable2}} praesentium, nisi culpa vero'">
<input id="run1" type="button" value="run">
<br />
<span id="output1"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example generated with regex101.com.
You can play with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/ldGDXz/1)

```
const regex = /{{(.*?)}}/gm;
const str = `Lorem ipsum dolor {{variable1}}, sit amet consectetur {{otherVaraible}} elit. Iure facilis quaerat obcaecati tempore {{variable2}} praesentium, nisi culpa vero`;
const subst = `${$1}`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```